# sed: remove all but pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file build like this:

> smthPATTERNsmthPATTERN
>   PATTERNsmthPATTERN
>   smthPATTERNsmthPATTERNPATTERN

The rules are:
'smth' can be anything but 'PATTERN'
each 'smth' can be different
'PATTERN' is well definable by regex

Is there sed command to remove all but pattern.
The result to above would be:

> PATTERNPATTERN
>   PATTERNPATTERN
>   PATTERNPATTERNPATTERN

If not sed than what?

Real example:

```
14:New: [42.083482 11945.506401 3791.240272], time 0.5000000  
34:New: [70.367422 11591.443051 3686.804348], time 2.4999999  
59:New: [55.001608 11181.824750 3529.426501], time 4.4999999  
84:New: [46.503589 10733.180988 3400.994526], time 6.4999999  
109:New: [48.331394 10438.083437 3321.319648], time 8.5000000  
134:New: [42.924864 10101.462941 3208.426613], time 10.5000000
```

PATTRN is a floating point number (regex [0-9]*\.[09]*)
I expect result like that:

```
42.083482 11945.506401 3791.240272 0.5000000  
70.367422 11591.443051 3686.804348 2.4999999  
55.001608 11181.824750 3529.426501 4.4999999  
46.503589 10733.180988 3400.994526 6.4999999  
48.331394 10438.083437 3321.319648 8.5000000  
42.924864 10101.462941 3208.426613 10.5000000
```

Comment: in text processing, every character can be important.. if `-` is not part of your real input, don't put it in sample... finding a solution will depend on knowing nature of `pattern` and `smth`, so a more realistic sample would help... if you need a generic solution, use `perl` to extract only matching patterns and print them (with a delimiter between if needed).. that way it wouldn't matter where `smth` is placed, how many characters it is made up of, how many times it occurs, etc

Comment: For your "real example" you would do better to cut off the front and back sections using the square brackets as delimiters. eg: `sed "s/^[^[]*\[//; s/].*$//"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a substitution command with `sed` you could do:

```
sed -E  "s/smth-//g" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure `sed` regex doesn't easily allow you to say "anything except a pattern". Try

```
sed 's/[^p]\|p\($\|[^a]\)\|pa\($\|[^t]\)\|pat\($\|[^t]\)\|patt\($\|[^e]\)\|patte\($\|[^r]\)\|patter\($\|[^n]\)//g'
```

Modern regex such as Perl's lets you easily do

```
perl -pe 's/(?!pattern).//g'
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to define "-" as field separator and after that act like a normal substitution so sed /s/...